# Apache POI set cell border is not working

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm facing an issue with Apache POI (v 4.1.2) where it can't set the border as THIN.
My code is supported for both XLS and XLSX extensions. When I export data to XLSX file, everything is OK, but with XLS files, it doesn't draw the border from cell **K5** to the end.

[image: Issue image]

Here is my code:

```
private int populateExcelData(Workbook workbook, Sheet sheet, int rowNum, List<List<Object>> excelData,
            ExcelVo excelVo, Boolean isHeader) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(excelData)) {
            int cellNum = 0;
            Row row;
            for (List<Object> objects : excelData) {
                cellNum = excelVo.getColPadding();
                row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
                Cell cell;
                for (Object object : objects) {
                    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
                    setCellValue(cell, object, excelVo);
                    configCellStyle(cell, workbook, excelVo, isHeader);
                }
            }
        }
        return rowNum;
    }

private void configCellStyle(Cell cell, Workbook workbook, ExcelVo excelVo, Boolean isHeader) {
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
        if (isHeader) {
            Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
            headerFont.setBold(true);
            headerFont.setColor(excelVo.getFontColor().getIndex());
            cellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(excelVo.getBackgroundColor().getIndex());
        }
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
```

I don't know why with XLS files it ONLY draws the border from cell **K5** onward. The code doesn't throw a bug or exception.

Thank all for your support.

Comment: There are [Excel limits for unique cell formats/cell styles as well as for fonts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). Cell styles and fonts are stored on workbook level. They are shared for all cells in all worksheets. So don't create a separate cell style for each cell as you hit the limit then very fast. Former versions of `Excel` (binary `*.xls`) had even smaller limits. Thats why it works using newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [Excel limits for unique cell formats/cell styles as well as for fonts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). Cell styles and fonts are stored on workbook level. They are shared for all cells in all worksheets. Current Excel versions limits are:

> Unique cell formats/cell styles: 65,490

and

> Unique font types: 1,024 global fonts available for use; 512 per
> workbook

Former versions of Excel (binary *.xls) had even smaller limits.

So if you create a separate cell style for each cell, as you are doing, you will hit the limit very fast. `XSSF` may work as the limits are larger. But former versions of Excel (binary *.xls) had even smaller limits. Thats why it works not using `HSSF`.

So what to do is, creating as much cell styles as needed for the workbook *once* on workbook level. Do this *outside* the cell filling process. While creating the cells itself, the cell style only gets applied using `cell.setCellStyle`. But it cannot be created then.

Let's have a complete example to show this. It partially uses your code of `populateExcelData` but I only can hope it meets your ideas since you not had provided a complete example.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

public class CreateExcel {

 private Workbook workbook;
 private CellStyle textStyle;
 private CellStyle dateStyle;
 private CellStyle numberStyle;
 private CellStyle headerStyle;

 public CreateExcel(String type, String path, List<List<Object>> headerData, List<List<Object>> excelData) {
  try {
   this.workbook = ("HSSF".equals(type)) ? new HSSFWorkbook() : new XSSFWorkbook(); 

   DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();

   this.textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   setCellStyleAllBorders(textStyle);

   this.dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("DDDD, MMMM, DD, YYYY"));
   setCellStyleAllBorders(dateStyle);

   this.numberStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   numberStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00 \" Coins\""));
   setCellStyleAllBorders(numberStyle);

   this.headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
   headerFont.setBold(true);
   headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
   headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
   headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
   headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
   setCellStyleAllBorders(headerStyle);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   int rowNum = 0;
   rowNum = populateExcelData(workbook, sheet, rowNum, headerData, 1, true);

   rowNum = populateExcelData(workbook, sheet, rowNum, excelData, 1, false);
   
   System.out.println(rowNum);

   for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(c); // this is very time consuming, would be better one can set column widths using Sheet.setColumnWidth(int columnIndex, int width) directly
   }

   FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(path);
   this.workbook.write(fileout);
   fileout.close();
   this.workbook.close();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace(); 
  }
 }

 private int populateExcelData(Workbook workbook, Sheet sheet, int rowNum, List<List<Object>> excelData, Integer colPadding, Boolean isHeader) {
  if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(excelData)) {
   int cellNum = 0;
   Row row;
   for (List<Object> objects : excelData) {
    cellNum = colPadding;
    row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    Cell cell;
    for (Object object : objects) {
     cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
     setCellValueAndStyle(cell, object, isHeader);
    }
   }
  }
  return rowNum;
 }

 private void setCellValueAndStyle(Cell cell, Object object, Boolean isHeader) {
  if (object instanceof String) {
   cell.setCellValue((String) object);
   if (!isHeader) cell.setCellStyle(this.textStyle);
  } else if (object instanceof Double) {
   cell.setCellValue((Double) object);
   if (!isHeader) cell.setCellStyle(this.numberStyle);
  } else if (object instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
   cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar) object);
   if (!isHeader) cell.setCellStyle(this.dateStyle);
  }
  if (isHeader) cell.setCellStyle(this.headerStyle);
 }

 private void setCellStyleAllBorders(CellStyle cellStyle) {
  cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  List<List<Object>> headerData = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Object> headerRow = new ArrayList<>();
  headerRow.add("Text"); headerRow.add("Value"); headerRow.add("Date");
  headerData.add(headerRow);
  headerRow = new ArrayList<>();
  headerRow.add("not formatted"); headerRow.add("in Coins"); headerRow.add("as long date");
  headerData.add(headerRow);

  List<List<Object>> excelData = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int r = 1; r < 1000; r++) {
   List<Object> excelRow = new ArrayList<>();
   excelRow.add("Text" + r); excelRow.add(123.45 * r); excelRow.add(new GregorianCalendar(2020, 0, r));
   excelData.add(excelRow);
  }

  CreateExcel test = new CreateExcel("HSSF", "./Excel.xls", headerData, excelData);
  test = new CreateExcel("XSSF", "./Excel.xlsx", headerData, excelData);
 }
}
```